# How to prevent floating numbers getting round off in perl?

Tags: perl

I am getting some numbers from various sources with different length in its float. I am summing all the numbers as it is. The numbers are automatically round off. Someone please suggest to prevent the auto round off in perl.

The sample snippet is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $x=200.1564867256545456457;
my $y=3352.25654454545454;

print "X : $x\n Y : $y\n";
```

Comment: math::round [reference](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Round/Round.pm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot change the fact that there are a finite number of [floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) numbers whereas there are uncountably many real numbers.

You always have the option of reading and printing them as strings without modification. However, the moment you carry out any arithmetic, you are in floating point land.

You have two alternatives: 1. You can print numbers using more digits than the default using [printf/sprintf](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#sprintf-FORMAT-LIST); or 2. You can try to use arbitrary precision arithmetic. The latter is bound to be much slower and you need to be careful about how you initialize your variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %n = (
    x => 200.1564867256545456457,
    y => 3352.25654454545454,
);

printf "%s = %.18f\n", $_, $n{$_} for qw/x y/;
```

Output:

```
x = 200.156486725654531256
y = 3352.256544545454289619
```

This illustrates the fact that most real numbers cannot be represented using floating point numbers.

Using [Math::BigFloat](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigFloat;
Math::BigFloat->accuracy(24);

my %n = (
    x => Math::BigFloat->new('200.1564867256545456457'),
    y => Math::BigFloat->new('3352.25654454545454'),
);

print "$_ = $n{$_}\n" for qw/x y/;
```

Output:

```
x = 200.156486725654545645700
y = 3352.25654454545454000000
```

Comment: Or store and print them as strings, `$x = "200.1564867256545456457";`.

Comment: @ Kusalananda: How could I sum if i have converted into sting?

Comment: There's also Math::BigRat which stores numbers as fractions with integral numerators and denominators. Whatever *floats* your boat.